# Paypal Sandbox IPN

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

I'm having trouble trying to integrate the [Wordpress Simple Paypal Shopping Cart](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-simple-paypal-shopping-cart/) plugin into my Wordpress site. I've installed the plugin and on the settings have configured it to use the PayPal Sandbox.

When making a purchase, the IPN notification fails - I've checked this by logging into the PayPal Sandbox with the seller account and checking the IPN history. All IPN requests have a status of `failed`, a retry count of `8` and no HTTP response code. Further more, attempting to edit the IPN settings in the PayPal Sandbox account, and entering the IPN URL of my website results in the error:

```
We were unable to validate the URL you have entered. Please check your entry and try again.
```

When using the PayPal IPN Simulator, I've had some successful requests and some failures. For failures, I receive the error:

```
IPN was not sent, and the handshake was not verified. Review your information.
```

I've followed Step 1 (Local testing) of [these instructions](https://www.angelleye.com/test-paypal-ipn/) and can see the request is received, although verification fails (which is to be expected as the request has not come from PayPal):

```
[09/10/2018 6:56 PM] - SUCCESS :Connecting to: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr
[09/10/2018 6:56 PM] - FAILURE :IPN validation failed
```

I'm using HTTPS (not HTTP) for the notification URL, and the notification URL is not localhost.

In summary:

- Local testing works 100% of the time (but obviously fails at the IPN verification step)
- Paypal IPN Simulator works some of the time
- Actual Sandbox testing never works - and attempting to edit the IPN settings and add the IPN notification URL I've had working through the IPN Simulator results in an error

Comment: You mentioned wordpress. Do you have any application based firewall/blocker plugin installed like Wordfence?

Comment: I have [All in One WP Security and Firewall](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-security-and-firewall/) however I've tried disabling the plugin but it made no difference. If it was a firewall issue, it seems odd that the IPN Simulator would work some of the time

Comment: I guess you have entered a correct live notification URL and turned it on in PayPal settings?

Comment: Are you meaning the bit where you configure the IPN URL when I log into the seller PayPal account? If so, I've tried this but get the error `We were unable to validate the URL you have entered. Please check your entry and try again.` when it tries to validate the URL. Using the same URL in the PayPal IPN simulator works (sometimes)